# DataPickerDialog, ondateset in other fragment

Tags: java, android, facebook, dialog, datepicker

I got a problem right here, so this is my fragment:

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment  implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

//Click on the datetextview       
        txtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                  newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                  }

          });
```

As you can see whenever somewhin click on my textview a DatePickerDialog pops up.

I that same fragment I got the onDateSet:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Result: " );

    //Start again
    ShowEventsFromFQL();
}
```

Which is a log and a method to start.

This is my DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    private OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener;

    public DatePickerFragment() {}

    public void setOnDateSetListener(OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener) {
        this.onDateSetListener = onDateSetListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), onDateSetListener, year, month, day);
    }

}
```

Whenever they click on the textview a datepicker show up. So that works. But whenever the date is set nothing happens while I have a LOG in my ondateset.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never call your

```
setOnDateSetListener(OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener)
```

method on your DatePickerFragment.

so when creating your DatePickerFragment do

```
 DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
 newFragment.setOnDateSetListener(this);
 newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Comment: if I do that i get this: The method setOnDateSetListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type DialogFragment

Comment: as you can see i changed the type of DialogFragement to DatePickerFragment in the line above that